# Child module not inheriting profile from parent pom

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have a parent and child pom. The parent defines some profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then the children defines more properties for these profiles.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <name>serviceA</name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If I call only the child profile `mvn help:effective-pom  -pl child` the properties defined in the parent don't show. It only shows the children one, so the parent is somehow forgotten.

Is there any way I can inherit the parent and modify/extend in the children?

**Edit 1:** Possible answer
I have found [this link](http://www.dashbay.com/2011/03/maven-profile-inheritance/) where they say:

> Unfortunately, parent pom inheritance has some limits.  One of them is that profiles aren’t inherited.

So maybe it is not possible. What do you guys think? Have things changed in these years?

**Edit 2:** Properties are inherited somehow

By running mvn help:effective-pom -Plocal I get

```
...
<properties>
        <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
        <name>serviceA</name>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
       <id>local</id>
       <properties>
          <name>serviceA</name>
       </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

So I guess for only properties it seems that somehow are inherited.

Answer (score 3):

As you have found out already, two profiles with the same `<id>` aren’t merged during POM inheritance. What you can do as a workaround, however, is to have **two** profiles with different `<id>` but with the same [`<activation>` condition](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local-parent</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>local</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local-child</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>local</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <name>serviceA</name>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Running the build with `-Dlocal` rather than `-P local` now activates **both** profiles, which jointly have the desired effect.

Comment: I like your solution. I have also notices that properties are inherited from parent pom, that is, if I define a property under a profile in the parent, when calling the children this property is also inherited in value as "global" properties. Just see my Edit2.